# Understanding which Issuer Firebase Auth uses

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, jwt

I'm trying to understand the difference in JWT tokens when using tokens vs cookies...

When a user successfully authenticates using `signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)`, I get `userCred` of type `UserCredential`, which contains a `.user`

If I call `user.getIdToken()`, I get back a string which is the base-64 representation of the JWT token.

Decoding that JWT token, I get the issuer:

`"iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/queti-dev"`

This all matches the documentation on [verifying ID Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library).

However, if I pass in that token to `createSessionCookie`:

```
  const firebaseSessionCookie = await serverAdminAuth.createSessionCookie(jwtOidcTokenString, {})
```

The string that is returned is a base-64 representation of a different JWT token with a different issuer:

`"iss": "https://session.firebase.google.com/my-project"`

Which matches the documentation on verifying a [session cookie](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#verify_session_cookies_using_a_third-party_jwt_library).

Why is it that when it creates a cookie from the JWT token that a new token is created with different issuers?

Comment: It might help if you explain in the question why you expect them to be the same, or describe the problem that you're trying to overcome here.  It's completely different code and processes doing the issuing in either case.